# How to comment a line directly from bash using vim?

Tags: comments, invocation, bash

What I usually do from bash/vim ... is

- open file with vim
- go to line to comment
- comment a line
- save and quit

My file is `/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini` and the initial content is

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-xdebug/xdebug.so"
```

I want to run a command that in one statement adds `;` at the beginning of the second line.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-xdebug/xdebug.so"
```

Is it possible to do this directly from bash?

Comment: this is trivial to do with command line text processing tools like sed..  for ex: `sed -i '2 s/^/;/' file` to add `;` at beginning of 2nd line and `sed -i '2 s/.//' file` to delete first character from 2nd line... see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3120/address-and-address-range#t=201610281356079663598) for more such examples and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3640/in-place-editing/12529/portable-use#t=201610281357013942895) for use of `-i` flag for different sed versions

Comment: also, I think you missed out adding `;` in question to show before and after example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
vim +'normal! 2GI;' +'x' path/to/your/file
```

The `+` parameter allows to execute a command after opening the buffer.

The first command `normal! 2GI;` goes to line 2 and add a `;` at the beginning of the line

The second command saves and exit.

---

Bonus point: To uncomment the same line:

```
vim +'normal! 2G^x' +'x' path/to/your/file
```

Comment: What exactly second param "+'x'" means?

Comment: @sensorario See [`:h :x`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Ax). The command `:x` is the equivalent of the command `:wq` i.e. save and exit.

Comment: `:x` is not fully equivalent to `:wq` as it does not write when there are no changes (timestamp is preserved)